# C programming looping switch case if the it is default

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, switch-statement

I am using switch case for my boolean expression with answer either yes or no. But i want it to loop back if the answer is invalid. How do i use if or while loop with answer in Character can varies up as 'y' 'Y' 'n' 'N'? could the below if statement work?

```
if (mstatus != 'y', 'Y', 'N', 'n')
{
    switch(mstatus)
        case 'y':
            printf("You have answer yes for married");
            break;
        case 'Y':
            printf("You have answer yes for married");
            break;
        case 'n':
            printf("You have answer no for married");
            break;
        case 'N':
            printf("You have answer no for married");
            break;
}
else
{
    default:
        printf("please re-enter a valid answer");
        scanf(" %c", &mstatus);
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and indent the code properly.

Comment: A case (pun intended) for fall-through switch-case logic if ever there was one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general format for the `switch` statement is the following :

```
switch(expression) {

    case constant-expression  :
        statement(s);
        break; /* optional */

    case constant-expression  :
        statement(s);
        break; 
      .
      .
      .

   default : 
       statement(s);
       break;
```

This means that the `default` choice will be selected of none of the cases is matched. So you do not need to include the `default` case in and [else](/questions/tagged/else) statement. You can have a further look about [switch](/questions/tagged/switch) at [this link.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/switch_statement_in_c.htm)

If you want to continuously read a character until you match one of the cases, include the `switch` inside a [for](/questions/tagged/for) loop, like this :

```
int flag = 0;
for (; flag == 1;)
{
    switch(mstatus)
    {
        case 'y':
        case 'Y':
            printf("You have answer yes for married");
            flag = 1;
            break;
        case 'n':
        case 'N':
            printf("You have answer no for married");
            flag = 1;                
            break;
        default:
            printf("please re-enter a valid answer");
            scanf(" %c", &mstatus);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `if..else`block there at that way, at all.

In case `mstatus` is not having either of `y', 'Y', 'N', 'n'`, the control will go to the `default` case.

You can, however, put the `switch` statement block in a `while(1)`/ `while(someFlag)` loop and (un)set the `someFlag` when you want to *break out* of the looping.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement doesn't work as you cannot compare a variable with a range of values. Also, the `switch` statement is probably overkill. If you're just looking to loop around until you get a correct answer then you could do something like this:

```
for(;;)
{
  char mstatus;
  printf("please enter a marriage status");
  scanf(" %c", &mstatus);

  if(mstatus == 'y' || mstatus =='Y')
  {
    printf("You have answer yes for married");
    break;
  }
  else if(mstatus == 'n' || mstatus =='N')
  {
    printf("You have answer no for married");
    break;
  }
  else
  {
    printf("please re-enter a valid answer");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you provided, you have not added a loop at all. You need to add a loop for this to work.

Also, there is no need for an if, then else statement on top of a switch statement, as mentioned by Saurav.

There are many ways of doing this. One way is :

```
do
{
  printf("Answer (y/n)? :");
  scanf(" %c", &mstatus);
  repeat = 0;
  switch(mstatus)
  {
    case 'y':
    case 'Y':
      printf("You have answer yes for married");
      break;
    case 'n':
    case 'N':
      printf("You have answer no for married");
      break;
    default:
      printf("please re-enter a valid answer");
      repeat = 1;
  }
} while (repeat == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the logic in a function, that way you can return from the function when you want to exit the loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int yesno(const char *q)
{
    char answer = '\0';

    while (1) {
        printf("%s? (y/n) ", q);
        fflush(stdout);

        scanf(" %c", &answer);
        switch (answer) {
        case 'N':
        case 'n':
            return 0;
        case 'Y':
        case 'y':
            return 1;

        default:
            puts("Please answer y or n");
        }
    }

    /* unreachable */
    return -1;
}

int main(void)
{
    int yes;

    yes = yesno("Are you married");
    printf("You answered %s\n", yes ? "yes" : "no");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer provide me another insight to coding.